# Number of arrangements around a table

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

My doubt is based on two observations :

1) On top of a round table (which is rotatable) there are $n$ places to sit and we need to place $n$ people. How many ways is it possible to permute them ?

2) There are $n$ places to sit "around" a round table. How many ways is it possible to place $n$ people ?

My observation is that in the first case answer is $(n-1)!$ and in the second case it is $n!$ i.e. when the people are sitting on top of a table, rotation of the table makes $n$ permuations equivalent to one permutation. But, in the second case, rotation does not cause any change. Is this correct ?

Answer (score 2):

Fix the position of one person, then you have $n - 1$ left to arrange, for $(n - 1)!$ arrangements in all. The way you look at it makes no difference, both give the same answer (by the same argument).